# How can I let users chose their own email template?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an application where users can create emails, and I'd like them to be able to chose their email template design.

How might I implement this? I understand it may be a bit complex perhaps but I'm open to ideas.

newsletter.rb

```
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_presence_of :image, :name

  scope :for, ->(user) do
    if user 
      Newsletter.all
    end
  end

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable

  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_newsletters, through: :subscriptions, class_name: "Newsletter"
  has_many :newsletters

  validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :password, on: :create         

end
```

post.rb <---- this is what would go inside the template, the content from the post model.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :newsletter
end
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement the model relationships or the views?

Comment: cheers @eabraham ! A bit of both, I'm not sure if I should generate a new model for this i.e. template.rb, ultimately, when users are creating a post for their newsletter I'd like to allow them the ability to chose their email template. So any tips on what to do or where to start to accomplish this would be super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume it's a user preference of which template they wish to be sent.

```
User.newsletter_template = 'my_custom_template'
```

Now, create a generic activemailer template that simply renders the user's chosen template

**newsletter_email.html.erb**

```
<%= render "/some/path/#{user.newsletter_template}.html.erb" %>
```

**my_custom_template.html.erb**

```
<html>stuff</html>
```

**my_other_template.html.erb**

```
<html>alt template</html>
```

I know this isn't an in-depth explanation. Don't be shy to ask!

Comment: Thanks, +1 this is helpful! I do have a few questions. 1. Where is the newsletter_template method defined? Is it a user model method or should I create a seperate newsletter_template model? 2. How does the user actually choose the template? I.e. checkbox? or how would that work?

Comment: 1. create an attribute for the User model. Name it whatever you want. 2. I would probably use a <select> form, for the user to choose a SINGLE value from a preset list of templates you created.

Comment: Okay great, just to be clear it would be a new column on the users table or posts table in my case i.e newsletter_template:string, and I would pre populate it with my newsletters and then on a select form the user could choose with template right? And I will accept.